# SQL Server 2005 using case in order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table looks like this AFTER UNION

```
St
----
FUT  
80CE  
79CE  
81PE  
79PE
```

I need

```
St
----
FUT  
79CE   
80CE   
81PE   
79PE
```

Using this:

```
order by 
   case St
      when 'FUT' then 1 else 2 end ,
   case 
      when St like '%PE' then St end,
   case 
      when St like '%CE' then St  end
```

I get this:

```
St
----
FUT    
79CE    
80CE    
79PE    
81PE
```

Comment: Show your full query and table structure

Comment: Could you explain in words how you expect your result to be ordered? Your expected result doesn't make it clearer to me.

Comment: Your current result looks correct to me.

Comment: sir, first record 'FUT' ,then St like 'CE'order by ASC, then St like 'PE' order by DESC.But after FUT i get both 'CE' &' PE' in ASC

Comment: @gopi: to repeat my comment I made to a previous question of yours: well, storing multiple pieces of information into a single column like this is a mess - always - and it violates the first normal form of database design. IF you have multiple pieces of information (NIFTY, 14, JUL, FUT) - you should store those in separate columns - then querying would be really easy, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could use `ROW_NUMBER()` to order the data in a common table expression, that would allow you to easily use the row number in the ordering `CASE`;

```
WITH unionresult AS (
  <original query here>
), cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY st) rn
  FROM unionresult
)
SELECT st FROM cte 
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN st = 'FUT' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
  CASE WHEN St LIKE '%PE' THEN -rn END,
  CASE WHEN St LIKE '%CE' THEN  rn END
```

[A simple SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7adc2/1).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
order by case St
when 'FUT' then 1 else 2 end ,
case when St like '%CE' then 1 else 2 end ,
case when St like '%PE' then St end DESC,
case when St like '%CE' then St  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like  this

```
select st,case when id like '%PE' then 2 else 1
end "ord" from (
select * from t order by case st
when 'FUT' then 1 else 2 end ,
case when st like '%PE' then stend desc,
case when st like '%CE' then st end) as a order by
ord,case st
when 'FUT' then 1 else 2 end
```